# How to ReWrite a MATLAB code to Python code about Iteration?

Tags: python, matlab, code-conversion

I met a problem.

I drew this figure below

[image]

with a MATLAB/Octave code

```
t=[0,0.01,0.98]
y2=cos(8*pi*t);
plot(t,y2);
```

I tried to write it to Python code, but failed.
I have something clue of python code as below

```
def drange(begin, end, step):
    n = begin
    while n+step < end:
     yield n
     n += step
```

Comment: @sacul Indeed, it's very similar to Python code. In fact, 0 means begin, 0.01 means step, 0.98 means end in MATLAB/Octave code.

Comment: please, write your try. Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, what you posted in both matlab AND python is a vector / list of floats. If you're looking for a range from 0 to 0.98 in python, you'll have to use `numpy`: `import numpy as np` followed by `t=np.arange(0,0.98,0.01)`

Comment: Also, please provide some more code as context.  This code is valid python, but based on your description it seems to be used to do something else.  But it isn't clear without code what that "something else" is.

Comment: @sacul: MATLAB ranges include the end while numpy ones don't.  So it would need to be `np.arange(0, 0.99, 0.01)`

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I've already added more code

Comment: @TheBlackCat. np.linspace is probably a good approximation here too.

Comment: Hi Roc, if you are absolutely new to Python I can recommend reading this:http://www.scipy-lectures.org/

Comment: @Moritz I have a basic knowledge of Python, but your suggestion is helpful to me!

Answer (score 3):

Your `MATLAB` code does not create the plot you showed. This is because `t` is not a range, but a vector of the 3 values 0, 0.01 and 0.098, so instead, it plots only those 3 points:

[image]

## Fixing your `MATLAB` code

To create the plot you showed in `MATLAB`, you can do this:

```
t=[0:0.01:0.98];
y2=cos(8*pi*t);
plot(t,y2);
```

Notice the use of the `:` instead of the `,`, to specify that you want a range of values from 0 to 0.98 with a step of 0.01, rather than the vector of the three values 0, 0.01 and 0.98.

## Recreating the plot in `python`:

use [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), as well as the `cos` and `pi` functions provided by `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0,0.99,0.01)
y = np.cos(8*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Given that 0.98 and 0.99 are inexact and the rounding may be off, I would use something like 0.985 as the limit to ensure the correct number of points. Alternatively, you can use `np.linspace(0.0, 0.98, 99)`

Comment: Those are just nitpicks. Excellent answer. Good job addressing all of OP's issues.